# Logo Image not loading - PHP

Tags: php, image, loading

I'm working on a template file and I came across something that's biting my head.

On the header.php file I have the following

```
<div id="logo">
<a href="index.php"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="MY COMPANY""/></a>
<p class="tagline">MY COMPANY</p>
```

However the logo.png file is not showing up. only the alt= text and the "tagline" show up.

1. The .png file is in the images folder
2. The css file is properly configured (at least to my knowledge)
3. the header.php file is outside the 'images' folder so the image path should be ok.

this is my css code just for reference.

```
#logo {
float:left;
margin:22px 0 0 0;
}
#logo a {
    float:left;
    }
#logo .tagline {
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    width:115px;
    line-height:14px;
    color:#aeaeae;
    margin:0 0 0 10px;
    padding-top:5px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Most probably something with your path is wrong. Open the source code in your browser and click on the image link, does it load? No? Well then make sure you write correct paths.

Comment: Also, this is not a programming question, it's too localized, not constructive and a multiplicate.

Comment: It was a path issue. I had to add <img src="templates/templatename/images/logo.png" alt="MY COMPANY"/>. As @markus-tharkun suggested I noticed that when I right clicked on the image text and tried to load the image, it would try to find the path to the images folder from root. I don't understand why it would do that if the php file is just outside the images folder but this will do for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a mistake in your imgtag syntax, remove closing " at the end of alt attribute

```
<img src="images/logo.png" alt="MY COMPANY"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

your extra " prevents the img tag from closing causing your problems (highlighted with [])

```
<a href="index.php"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="MY COMPANY"["]/></a>
```

Comment: Checked that and corrected it but that wasn't the issue. thanks tho'

Answer (score 1):

I bit that your PHP is hosted on linux host, check file permissions of your image and its folder.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the relative path instead? Something like "/path of your web app/images/logo.png" . It might also be a file permission or misspelling.

Comment: That's not a relative path. That's an absolute path. Relative would be `../images/blah` or `./blah` or `../../blah`.